# Closing Minecraft is Crashing KDE/XFCE

Tags: nvidia, java, kde, xfce, minecraft

Closing minecraft causes both KDE and XFCE to crash, flashing rapidly. I am using the proprietary Nvidia drivers on a GTX 1060. There is nothing in the logs.

Xorg.0.log:

```
[  4335.735] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[  4335.735] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[  4335.735] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 1440.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
```

Comment: then bring us the kwin compositor logs

Comment: Where do I find those? I am running XFCE now and have done a full reinstall.

Comment: Remove old Minecraft and run- `sudo snap install minecraft`